# Chrome and Firefox strange behavior on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I developed a website at [this address](http://vijegan.com).

As you can see, everything seems to be fine including `get files from server(200 OK)` when a user visit the site, and every piece of code works correctly, including CSS and JS.

The problem is this:

The page looks good at the very first look, but the scroll is locked in Chrome and Firefox but surprisingly in IE 11 everything is fine.

I tried Firebug but couldn't find anything useful.

Could you take a look to my page and let me know what's wrong with the page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `<html>` tag has `overflow-y:hidden;`, which prevents scrolling. Maybe scrolling is supposed to be handled by some (non-functional) JavaScript code (e.g. nicescroll or parallax)?

Comment: but in localhost the page scroll correctly...!!!

Comment: You should include relevant code in the question. Just linking to the homepage makes the question useless for future visitors - as soon as you fix the problem nobody will be able to see the original code.

Comment: Also, you should read ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the most important parts of an HTML document.

You don't have opening `<html>` or `<head>` tags. This is critical, and probably a good part of the reason your site is busted.

While the tags show up in the inspector, they aren't there in the source. Chrome's inspector will add in missing opening/closing tags. Look at your source, you'll see.

Comment: well, these tags suppose to create dynamically and that part of code was returning false... Really thanks... My Daily up vote is reached today, I'll vote +1 tomorrow... :)